# How to check single value in coma seprated field using knex query PostGresSQl

Tags: node.js, select, knex.js

I have a table of cities where zipcodes are coma seprated as below sample

```
CityId   CountryId   StateId  CityName   Zipcodes
1        1           1        NewYork    16066,15825,35114
2        1           1        Cranbarry  11478,88544,97544
```

So like this i have bunch of data for US cities and zipcodes

but when i try to search it using `Knex Query` how can i write a same query we use to search in `MySql`

```
Select * from cities Where FIND_IN_SET('16066',Zipcodes)
```

> **Note:** FIND_IN_SET is unsupported in Knex and PostGresSql

in knex query. or is there any other way to find a cities by zipcode in this coma seprated value using Knex query

As the platform i am working is Node.js with PostGresSQl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by converting string in to the array here is your answer

```
SELECT id,name, zipcode FROM cities, 
unnest(string_to_array(zipcode, ',')) AS zipcodes  
where 
zipcodes = ANY ( string_to_array('16066', ',') ) group by id
```